# CentOs 5 - rsh - poll:protocol failure in circuit set

Tags: python, centos

There are some python scripts in my workspace which test a couple of features, and one of this scripts, in a small period of time, calls a lot of rsh commands.

When trying to run this one, I'm getting this error message :

> poll:protocol failure in circuit set

When I call the command that generates this error in normal shell, it works. And it works when running in another systems.

The command line:

```
rsh -l user host "grep MUST_RECORD_NEW_DATA $CONF_DIR/file.conf | grep -v MUST_RECORD_NEW_DIRECTORY"
```

Can anybody help me?